# Adding multiple custom markers and cluster them

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have this acitivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ClusterManager<GasStationItem> mClusterManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_gas_station);

    try {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            setUpClusters();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void setUpClusters(){
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<GasStationItem>(this, mMap);

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new OwnIconRendered(this ,mMap ,mClusterManager));

    addItems();
}

private void addItems(){

    ParseQuery<GasStationItem> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(GasStationItem.class);
    query.setLimit(100);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<GasStationItem>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<GasStationItem> gasStationItems, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for (int i=0; i< gasStationItems.size(); i++){
                    GasStationItem gasStationItem = gasStationItems.get(i);
                    mClusterManager.addItem(gasStationItem);
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("ERROR:", "" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}

class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<GasStationItem> {

    private BitmapDescriptor mBitmapMarker;

    public OwnIconRendered(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                           ClusterManager<GasStationItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(GasStationItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        mBitmapMarker = customizeMarkers(item.getName());
        markerOptions.icon(mBitmapMarker);
        markerOptions.title(item.getName());
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }
}


private BitmapDescriptor customizeMarkers(String input){

    BitmapDescriptor bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    if(input.contains("Gazprom")){
        bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.gazprom);
    } else {
        if(input.contains("Mol")) {
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mol);
        } else {
            if(input.contains("Petrom")){
                bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.petrom);
            } else {
                if(input.contains("OMV")){
                    bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.omv);
                } else {
                    if(input.contains("Lukoil")){
                        bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.lukoil);
                    } else {
                        if(input.contains("Rompetrol")){
                            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.rompetrol);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bitmapMarker;
}
}
```

LatLng for markers i read it form database, i use parse for that.Also i override Renderer to customize my markers.

When I launch the activity not even the map si draw. The single error from logcat which i think is relative is:

> 03-20 00:31:51.425    1996-1996/com.driverbuddy.costeiu.driverbuddy
>   I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happening because you are performing heavy operations in main thread.

Android is single threaded system, there is single main thread where all the other subsystem hooks upon to perform task such as Activities, Services, Content Providers etc.

You would want to move your setUpClusters() to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i've created new class witch extends AsynkTask, i move only setUpClusters() calling method and perform in onCreate() : new class.execute(); and nothing happening